# array looping and plotting from a function in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a function to compute the total cost `deltav` and time of flight `tof` of a circular to circular orbit tranfer from r1 and r2, the function is as such:

```
function [deltav, tof] = fasttransfer(r1, r2, mu)

% Part 1 - function to compute the total cost deltav and tof
% global r1 r2 mu

% velocity of initial and final orbits (km/s)
v1 = sqrt(mu/r1);
v2 = sqrt(mu/r2);

% transfer orbit semimajor axis
at = (r1+r2)/2;

% transfer orbit eccentricity
et = (max(r1, r2) - min(r1, r2))/(r1+r2);

% semimajor axis, perigee, apogee, and velocities of transfer orbit
rp = at*(1.0-et);
ra = at*(1.0+et);
vt1 = sqrt((2.0*mu/rp)-(2.0*mu/(rp+ra)));
vt2 = sqrt((2.0*mu/ra)-(2.0*mu/(rp+ra)));

% cost of transfer
if (r2>r1)
    % higher to lower transfer
    dv1 = vt1 - vt1;
    dv2 = v2 - vt2;
else
    %lower to higher transfer
    dv1 = v1 - vt2;
    dv2 = vt1 - v2;
end

% total cost deltav
deltav = abs(dv1) + abs(dv2);

% transfer orbit period (s) and time of flight
t = 2.0*pi*sqrt(at^3/mu);
tof = t/2;
end
```

What I want to do next is to plot `deltav` and `tof` as functions of r2/r1, on the same plot. I came up with this, and it's just a disaster trying to figure out error from the array operations.

```
global mu
mu = 398600; % earth gravitational constant (km^3/sec^2)
re = 6378; % earth radius (km)

alt1 = linspace(200,1000,800);
alt2 = linspace(383600,384400,800);
r1 = re + alt1;
r2 = re + alt2;


for i=1:length(r1)
    for j=1:length(r2)
deltav(1:j) = fasttransfer(r1, r2, mu);
tof(i:j) = fasttransfer(r1, r2, mu);
rratio(i:j) = r1./r2;
    end
end

yyaxis left
plot(deltav,rratio,'bo-')
xlabel('Orbit Ratio (r2/r1)')
ylabel('Transfer deltav')
hold on
yyaxis right
plot(tof,rratio,'ro-')
ylabel('time of flight')
hold off
```

Any help is appreciated!